# c# 4 radio button sum

Tags: c#, sum, radio-button

I have 16 Radio Button and I am trying to add the value of 4 radio button in each of 4 cases How can I do this? How do I get the sum of the sixteen radioButton.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    string ChosenMovie = "";

    if (radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        //label2.Text = "100";
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "100" + "\r\n";
    }        
    if (radioButton2.Checked)
    {
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "60" + "\r\n";
    }
    if (radioButton3.Checked)
    {
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "30" + "\r\n";
    }
    if (radioButton4.Checked)
    {
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "0" + "\r\n";
    }
    if (radioButton5.Checked)
    {
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "100" + "\r\n";
    }
    if (radioButton6.Checked)
    {
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "60" + "\r\n";
    }
    if (radioButton7.Checked)
    {
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "30" + "\r\n";
    }
    if (radioButton8.Checked)
    {
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "0" + "\r\n";
    }
    if (radioButton9.Checked)
    {
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "100" + "\r\n";
    }
    if (radioButton10.Checked)
    {
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "60" + "\r\n";
    }
    if (radioButton11.Checked)
    {
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "30" + "\r\n";
    }
    if (radioButton12.Checked)
    {
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "0" + "\r\n";
    }
    if (radioButton13.Checked)
    {
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "100" + "\r\n";
    }
    if (radioButton14.Checked)
    {
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "60" + "\r\n";
    }
    if (radioButton15.Checked)
    {
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "30" + "\r\n";
    }
    if (radioButton16.Checked)
    {
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "0" + "\r\n";     
        MessageBox.Show(ChosenMovie);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your program displaying something different than what you're expecting?  It's not clear what you're expecting it to display.  What are the 4 cases?

Comment: @gunnerone i am creating a form of multiple choice Questions in which a Questions have four choice and similarly others have same but at the the last all ticked ans should be added up

Comment: @gunnerone i hope you understand well

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is your problem, but your `MessageBox` will show up only if `radioButton16` is checked:

```
if (radioButton16.Checked)
{
    ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "0" + "\r\n";     
    MessageBox.Show(ChosenMovie);
}
```

You might also want to use StringBuilder for adding strings.

Comment: No, I don't think he want to use a StringBuilder